# Extract distinct values from XML based on attribute value

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I need to extract to `doc_num` and `x` for `kod = 'N'` from XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<main doc_num=99>
<item name="A">
    <Dok Kod="N" X="1" Id="5"/>
    <Dok Kod="N" X="4" Id="5"/>
</item>
<item name="B">
    <Dok Kod="N" X="1" Id="2"/>
    <Dok Kod="N" X="4" Id="6"/>
    <Dok Kod="N" X="5" Id="8"/>
    <Dok Kod="Z" X="4553" Id="8"/>
</item>
</main>
```

Output should look like this, I only need distinct:

```
doc_num     X
99          1
99          4
99          5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XMLTable with an Xpath that targets the `Kod=N` nodes, then walks back up the tree to get the `doc_num`; this version assumes your original value is a string:

```
select distinct xml.doc_num, xml.x
from your_table t
cross apply xmltable (
  '/main/item/Dok[@Kod="N"]'
  passing xmltype(t.your_xml)
  columns doc_num number path './../../@doc_num',
    x number path '@X'
) xml
```

```
DOC_NUM X
------- -
     99 1
     99 4
     99 5
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7df1aaa0e4327d8025042ba9236651bf)

If your original value is already XMLType then walking back up the tree doesn't work as expected - not sure if that's a bug but seems to happen in 11gR2 and 18c at least. You can work around that by converting to a string and back:

```
select distinct xml.doc_num, xml.x
from your_table t
cross apply xmltable (
  '/main/item/Dok[@Kod="N"]'
  passing xmltype(t.your_xml.getclobval())
  columns doc_num number path './../../@doc_num',
    x number path '@X'
) xml
```

```
DOC_NUM X
------- -
     99 1
     99 4
     99 5
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b73afdf45103c27d9b617664aa065ed5)

---

I've just noticed you tagged this for Oracle 11g... so cross apply isn't available, and walking back up the tree doesn't work either; neither does filtering on the child attribute name. So you can do this instead, with two levels of XMLTable:

```
select distinct xml1.doc_num, xml2.x
from your_table t
cross join xmltable (
  '/main'
  passing xmltype(t.your_xml)
  columns doc_num number path '@doc_num',
    doks xmltype path 'item/Dok'
) xml1
cross join xmltable (
  '/Dok'
  passing xml1.doks
  columns kod varchar2(1) path '@Kod',
    x number path '@X'
) xml2
where xml2.kod = 'N'
```

```
DOC_NUM X
------- -
     99 1
     99 4
     99 5
```

which works in 11g [with a string](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2dfe78fd165732ab98a92d24ed1794b7) or [with an XMLType](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=959cdf7f54dbf7a835a3b12b5a697509) source.